# matter.js circular area with bodies inside

Tags: typescript, react-native, matter.js

I'm trying to find a way to build a circular area with borders and put rigid bodies inside

Didn't find an easy way to make it.

There's [one example of a terrain](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/blob/master/examples/terrain.js) built from an SVG:

```
if (typeof $ !== 'undefined') {
        $.get('./svg/terrain.svg').done(function(data) {
            var vertexSets = [];

            $(data).find('path').each(function(i, path) {
                vertexSets.push(Svg.pathToVertices(path, 30));
            });

            terrain = Bodies.fromVertices(400, 350, vertexSets, {
                isStatic: true,
                render: {
                    fillStyle: '#2e2b44',
                    strokeStyle: '#2e2b44',
                    lineWidth: 1
                }
            }, true);

            World.add(world, terrain);

        });
    }
```

Am I right that I will have to use the same logic and add a lot of bodies (an approximation of PI) to build a circular area?

Comment: Sure, that should work. If you give it a try and get stuck, feel free to update with your code and I can try to help or offer an example.

Comment: [Related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58507514/matter-js-hollow-circle-body)